# Adding ceiling support for shelf posts

Tags: ceiling, post, support

I want to install a system like this one:
[image: Ikea posts]

It will be a bit more heavily loaded. I would like to get some structure in the ceiling to be able to install it solidly. Ideally something like a plywood sheet or a 2x4.

What's the proper way? The ceiling is currently opened and look like below. The parts with green tape used to support a closed closet but are now a bit shaky, after closet removal. They will probably go away.

The floor joist in the middle is very solid, I understand it to be supporting the floor above. Is it even recommended to drill/nail into it?

I'm only looking for strength in the lateral direction, here. I trust the posts to hold the downward force.

[image]

Comment: The long piece, what you call a beam is just a floor joist helping to hold up the floor above.  A main support beam is usually in the centre of the house and is three or more of those joists put together.  Ceiling support for those shelves will only prevent tipping over(which is nice), but not help with increase weight/load on the shelves.  Simple angle brackets screwed into the ceiling and shelve posts should work.

Comment: OP, that's a nice solution! Wish I found it when I asked [my question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/267376/115283). can you please indicate which system that is ? Thank you ! @crip659 good to see you also on this one ! :)

Comment: This is https://www.ikea.com/ca/en/cat/elvarli-system-35766/