# Shelves into single metal stud. Is it possible?

Tags: studs, shelving, brackets

I have seen many similar questions, but most are around mounting a TV. I'd like to mount some shelves to hold kitchen appliances (air fryer, coffee machine, toaster, etc). 4 shelves in total, 3 with max 10 kg (22 lbs), one at the top with 2 kg (4.5 lbs). Space is limited, so I would like to build the shelves on the *exact* dimensions (45cm wide, 30cm depth), and without frame, directly on the wall.

The wall is double plaster board with some mineral wool in between, separating kitchen from office. I am lucky there is a stud exactly where I'd need it. It's made of metal, but I'm not sure how wide it is. The wall is covered with ~1.5-2 cm of roughcast (crépis in French). For reference, I'm in Switzerland, in a fairly new building (2017).

Since the shelf width is smaller than the distance between 2 studs (45 vs 62 cm), I want to install on only 1 bracket. I've done the bottom shelf already, but it is rather wobbly: https://photos.app.goo.gl/4qV2naRyHuPsh8TZA . It's not the screws, but the bracket, which is [this one](https://www.hornbach.ch/fr/p/console-en-tole-dacier-l-44-x-h-350-x-p-300-mm-blanche/2441761/) (rated for 30 kg, 66lbs). I was hoping that the bracket taking screws on each side would prevent the wooden shelf from wobbling, and while this is true, the bracket doesn't have great torsion resistance.

So my questions are:

1. Would the metal stud support this load? Provided adequate screws and plugs/anchors.
2. If so, where would I find a stiffer bracket? I think a design like this would be ideal, but this is a creation for 3D printing [image]
3. Could I do without toggle bolts? The holes needed for those are huge. Staff at DYI store recommended [these](https://www.hornbach.ch/fr/p/cheville-longue-tri-5-31-100-unites/8229588/) (there is a pic for pure plasterboard, I'd be in metal stud).

Thank you all !

Comment: A single stud with one bracket is only good for weight right above the bracket.  I do not usually like using anchors for weight, one bracket in the centre on the stud plus two brackets at the ends with anchors/toggles might work.

Comment: In case of corner mounting like yours, "shelf width" is the diagonal.

Comment: In what way is the "wall fake"? I'm a bit confused by that. To improve wobble resistance, you'll really want to extend your shelf brackets to span 2 studs. Anything in just one stud is likely to wobble.

Comment: @Agent_L  I think the picture is only an example, OP is putting the shelves on a straight wall, not in a corner.

Comment: I'm confused.  Your links appear to show a flat wall, but your embedded pic is of a corner bracket.  As to the wobbliness, I think it's fair to have a bracket securely fastened to the stud to carry most of the load, and "outrigger" brackets to provide some stability against wobble.

Comment: @Huesmann  I think OP's idea was a single bracket that spread out/expanded the shelf holders, like a corner bracket.

Comment: @FreeMan I think OP is using "fake" to refer to what we typically wood call hollow walls, as opposed to say a solid brick/block/concrete/wood wall. I think solid walls are, relatively speaking, more common in Europe than in the US.

Comment: @crip659 is right regarding the bracket, this is a design that spreads horizontally to overcome wobbling, but mounted on flat surface. Wish it existed made of metal, though.

Comment: @crip659 what do you mean by "weight right above the bracket"? Weight that does not extend sideways? Also by "I do not usually like using anchors for weight". Thanks!

Comment: I mean to balance or put weight right on top of the bracket.  Weight away from the bracket will increase tipping force.  Anchors are okay  for stuff that does not weigh much, but for heavier, more expensive things I like to use studs to hold screws, not just drywall/plaster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use two brackets and mount one with clamping hollow-wall anchors. Double drywall is plenty strong for the light half of these loads. There are several types which take a 3/8" (~10mm) hole and hold quite firmly. No need to reinvent any wheels.

That said, yes, your solution could work. A single toggle bolt at the top of the bracket would theoretically support the entire thing (though you'd want two to prevent spin). The shelf keeps the bracket from swiveling sideways. The critical aspect would be keeping the shelf firmly attached to the bracket so it can't flip off. There will be substantial cantilever.

Comment: yes, this seems the reasonable thing. Though I'm not a fan of the 10mm holes :(. I did end up using multiple brackets, 1 in the metal stud, and two smaller ones on the side for balance. The side ones are with generic anchors, not toggles, but they seem to hold well

Why do you say only one with clamping anchors? Because the other is in the stud?

Comment: Yes. I'd probably use sheet metal screws there.

Answer (score 4):

My recommendation here is the same as for a TV:

- Cut a piece of plywood long enough to attach to two studs.
- Paint the plywood to match the rest of the wall. Even if you don't end up with an exact match, that will keep it from seeming out of place.
- Mount the shelves to the plywood using at least two sets of screws.

Comment: Thank you! Do you mean a large rectangular piece, or like one piece for each row of shelf, 4 in total?

Comment: A large rectangular piece. One piece will look better than multiple, be less work to install and be more stable.

Comment: Thank you! It's a good idea. Not sure wife will approve, but I'll try. I'm thinking that such a large piece might be heavy on its own, so ideally it would rest on the ground. This might be challenging due to the baseboard

Answer (score 0):

Apparently no, single bracket is not really feasible, as I could not find a bracket that is strong enough in torsion and supports the shelf well. The sturdies brackets have only 2 screws in a line, so the shelf still wobbles around them.

In the end, I added 2 extra brackets for each, one on each side, for some stability. These are anchored in the plasterboard, with "multi-purpose" anchors. Most of the weight is carried by the central bracket, which is in the stud.

[image: image of the shevles, from the front, seeing the 3 brackets per shelf, and a set of holes for the not yet mounted shelf]

I wish had found side brackets that needed only 2 holes instead of 3.

But it holds well

[image: picture of the shelves with the kitchen utensils fitten on top]